# MySQL Trigger to verify data before INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I want to create a trigger that verifies some data before inserting a row into a table. I have three tables:

Table Personnel:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Personal` (
  `IdPersonal` INT NOT NULL,
  `ApePaterno` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `ApeMaterno` VARCHAR(60) NULL,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `Direccion` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `FechaDeIngreso` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdPersonal`))
```

Table User:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Usuarios` (
  `idUsuario` INT NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Contrasenia` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `IdPersonal` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUsuario`),
  INDEX `fk_Usuario_Personal_idx` (`IdPersonal` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Usuario_Personal`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IdPersonal`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Personal` (`IdPersonal`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

And table Notes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Notas` (
  `idNota` INT NOT NULL,
  `Nota` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  `IdUsuario` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idNota`),
  INDEX `fk_IdUsuario_idx` (`IdUsuario` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_IdUsuario`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IdUsuario`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Usuarios` (`idUsuario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

So, an user can insert a note only if it is part of the personnel, so I tried to implement the next trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `Notas_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `Notas` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE IdInterno INT;
    SELECT IdPersonal INTO IdInterno
    FROM Usuarios WHERE idUsuario = new.IdUsuario;
    IF (IdInterno != null) THEN
        INSERT INTO Notas (Nota, IdUsuario)
        VALUES (new.Nota, new.IdUsuario);
    ELSE
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '50001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Las notas sólo pueden ser registradas por usuarios internos';
    END IF;
END
```

The idea is to get the Peronnel id from the users table and if it is null, don't insert anything into the table, but I can't make it work

Comment: It would be simpler, probably better, to just add a foreign key to Personal rather than Usuarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already in a trigger for insert on Notas, so if there's no reason to cancel it, just let it go through.

Also use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` when comparing something to NULL. Don't use `=` or `!=`, because NULL is not a value that is equal to or unequal to anything. I.e. `NULL = NULL` is not true.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `Notas_BEFORE_INSERT` 
  BEFORE INSERT ON `Notas` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE IdInterno INT;
    SELECT IdPersonal INTO IdInterno
    FROM Usuarios WHERE idUsuario = new.IdUsuario;
    IF (IdInterno IS NULL) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '50001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Las notas sólo pueden ser registradas por usuarios internos';
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I guess the main problem was Using ```=``` and ```!=``` instead NOT EQUALS

Comment: That was one problem, but the other problem was that you can't insert into the table inside a trigger for that same table.